# Spring Security with Multiple Authentications

Tags: java, spring, security

hi how i can use this orders for my controller and restController ....
like -> order 1 for html view and order 2 for rest api
i want use it for webapp using rest and mvc in spring

Multiple Entry Points With Multiple HTTP Elements

i think i should using order in my controller class!

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/LoginPage")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                    .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout().permitAll() `enter code here`
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(m.authenticationProvider());
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i work on this problem and find way for using spring rest api and spring mvc in single 
project this is easy to use them in one project with out security 
for **spring rest security** and **spring mvc security** with **login page** and **rest basic auth registery** in a project we should use **httpBasic()**

and for **url** use

**http://username:password@localhost:8080/api/members/**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultipleEntryPointsSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   @Autowired
   private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

   @Override
   protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
   }

// this is filter for mappings for api and mvc mappings
// http://username:password@localhost:8080/api/members/
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       http.authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
               .antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
               .antMatchers("/systems/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
               .and()

               .httpBasic()
               .and()

               .formLogin()
               .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
               .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
               .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
               .permitAll()
               .and()
               .logout().permitAll()
               .and()
               .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

   }

   @Bean
   public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }

   @Bean
   public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
       DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
       auth.setUserDetailsService(userService); //set the custom user details service
       auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder()); //set the password encoder - bcrypt
       return auth;
   }

}
```